# how to remove a whole line when it's blank in VSCode just like in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

When removing a line in IntelliJ if it's in brackets and if it's just white spaces the whole line would get removed, So I wanted to know if there is any way to make that happen in VSCode and if there is how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension called [Hungry delete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jasonlhy.hungry-delete), it did exactly what I wanted.